# historical antecedents of mathematical talks

Tags: ho.history-overview

Is there a general reference of how mathematical talks, say academic talks, evolve in history? Before the International Congress of mthematics, is there any antecedent of  todays talks?

Comment: I do not know of a general reference, and I think the question is rather vague, but here is an account of an early talk with   mathematical content:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meno_%28Plato%29#Dialogue_with_Meno.27s_slave

Comment: "On 28 November 1660, the 1660 committee of 12 announced the formation of a 'College for the Promoting of Physico-Mathematical Experimental Learning', which would meet weekly to discuss science and run experiments." -from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Society#Founding_and_early_years

Comment: I think there was a time when they didn't use PowerPoint.

Comment: @Jaime: if you want a glimpse of how the talks were in 1893 (which is much more specific than your original question), here is a write-up of Felix Klein's lectures at Northwestern University (Evanston, IL) in connection with World Fair in Chicago that took place the same year.  http://www.futuretg.com/FTHumanEvolutionCourse/FTFreeLearningKits/01-MA-Mathematics,%20Economics%20and%20Preparation%20for%20University/008-MA19-OP01-History%20of%20Mathematics,%20Oeuvres%20and%20Reference/Klein/Felix%20Klein%20-%20Lectures%20on%20Mathematics.pdf      (I was a grad student at NW some 100 years after).

Comment: Margaret: Thank you for sharing this beautiful reference. Now I have a glimpse   of how the talks were in 1893.

Comment: @MargaretFriedland the link in your comment is broken.

Comment: Somehow I cannot edit the original comment, but try this: https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc2.ark:/13960/t50g3k40z&view=1up&seq=7&skin=2021

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are interested to learn how Euler lectured on math and physics to a lay audience, you might want to take a look at the [Letters of Euler to a German Princess.](http://archive.org/details/letterseulertoa00eulegoog) This book collects the lectures on elementary science that Euler gave in Berlin to the Princess of Anhalt Dessau, in the early 1760's. Dominic Klyve gives a nice [overview](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/eulersociety/opusculum/Opusculum2010-2.pdf) of "Euler as Master Teacher".

For a more technical/advanced talk, the lecture which Riemann delivered on June 10, 1854 has been preserved [here](http://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/Geom.pdf). Dedekind writes about this lecture:

> Gauss sat at the lecture, which surpassed all his expectations and on the way back from the colloquium
>   meeting he spoke to Wilhelm Weber, with the greatest appreciation, and
>   with an excitement rare for him, about the depth of the ideas
>   presented by Riemann.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Euler taught that princess by correspndence. And that is the reason why we can read this.

Comment: certainly, as Euler himself writes: "The hope of having the honor to communicate in person to your highness my lessons in geometry becoming more and more distant, which is a very sensible mortification to me, I feel myself impelled to supply person instruction by writing, as far as the nature of the subjects will permit." Still, the style of the letters is quite informal and colloquial, I can imagine actually hearing Euler lecture.

Comment: The way we lecture has drastically changed in the last 200 years. We tend today to give more details. The answers I read are useful, but one thing is a paper, or a book,  and a different think is a talk. I have no idea of how were the talks in the XVII Century or later, o more recently, how were the talks in the ICM in Chicago (1893)? The ICM 1893 papers are on line available (http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/) but a glance at them suggest that the mathematical contents do not reflect entirely the talks. For example, how do they addressed the mathematical equations to the audience?